# opcache_is_script_cached function in php5.5.11

Tags: php, opcache

Recently I asked a question "is there a way to find if the script was hit by opCache" and was not able to find an answer. Right now looking at [changelog](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php) of **Php5.5.11**, I found that the new function

> OPCache:
>
> Added function opcache_is_script_cached().

was added. Based on the name it is doing exactly what I want, but the problem is that I can not find any [documentation on this function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.opcache.php).

Can anyone tell me exactly what this function does? Please refrain from wild guesses.

Comment: The function was actually officially released as part of PHP 5.6.0. Either way, I've added documentation for the function: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28547731/852382

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading this post (and some other PHP manual notes), I recognized that the function had still yet to be documented. Anyway, I've taken the small bit of time recently to add this function to the PHP documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-is-script-cached.php

An excerpt from the manual:

> opcache_is_script_cached — Tells whether a script is cached in OPCache
>
> `boolean opcache_is_script_cached ( string $file )`
>
> This function checks if a PHP script has been cached in OPCache. This can be used to more easily detect the "warming" of the cache for a particular script.
>
> Returns `TRUE` if `$file` is cached in OPCache, `FALSE` otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You will find the source code for that function at the bottom of [zend_accellerator_module.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/ccf863c8ce7e746948fb060d515960492c41ed27/ext/opcache/zend_accelerator_module.c), and it does appear to do what you want. It looks like it takes one argument, which is the script filename you're checking. The code in `filename_is_in_cache` seems to handle cases where the same file is specified by different strings ('filename.php' vs '/var/www/filename.php'), but you can dig deeper or test on your own to verify.

Also, here's a [test case](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/c3b35e25192e99dfe5b6b94da02cec2913a44510/ext/opcache/tests/is_script_cached.phpt) showing an example, though it's very minimal.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, a documented function [opcache_get_status](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-get-status.php) does what You want. Just call it by passing `true` parameter in it and checking a `scripts` section in the returned array.